# Mathematica Plotting Solve Results

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

```
Remove["Global`*"]
a = 0;
For[z = 0, z < 3, z++, Sol[a] = x /. Solve[z^2 + x == 10, x]; 
 a = a + 1;]
```

I am new to the mathematica so I'm experimenting with it.Answer of the problem changes at every loop so I stored them inside an array.
I can see the numeric results using `Do[Print[Sol[a]], {a, 0, 2}];` but how can I plot the results I tried using `Plot[Sol[[a]], {a, 0, 2}]` but it didn't work.

Comment: Try `Sol=Table[x/.Solve[z^2+x==10,x],{z,0,2}];Plot[Sol,{p,0,5},AxesOrigin->{0,0}]` which calculates your list of solutions and then plots them. `Plot` accepts a list of expressions and plots all of them in the same graphic. The `p` just serves to tell it over what range you want to do the plot. The `AxesOrigin`  is optional and you can see how the plot is different if you omit that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Remove["Global`*"]
func = z^2 + x == 10;
sol = Solve[func, x];
Plot[x /. sol, {z, 0, 3}]
```

[image]